# Python: Extracting specific words from a string

Tags: python, string, split, character

I currently have a program which web-scrapes data from a website and prints it out for the user. However, it also prints out parts of the scraped data which I don't want. This isn't all of the code, it's an ungodly amount for the little thing I need to actually do, but these are the lines which are needed.

```
#https://tradingeconomics.com/united-kingdom/indicators
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

web_add = 'https://tradingeconomics.com/united-kingdom/indicators'
web_data = requests.get(web_add)
bs = BeautifulSoup(web_data.text, "html.parser")

up_GDPgrowthRate = str(bs.findAll("td")[21])

varNameBlacklist = "¬`1234567890!\"£$%^&*()_-+=/{[]}:;@'~#|\\<>,.?"

up_GDPgrowthRate = up_GDPgrowthRate.translate({ord(i): None for i in varNameBlacklist})
print(up_GDPgrowthRate)
```

This is the output:

```
td stylepaddingleft px textalign left fontweight  whitespace normal
a hrefunitedkingdomgdpgrowth

                                                            GDP Growth Rate

                                                            span classtableunit smallspan
atd
```

The only part I need is "GDP Growth Rate". I've tried most of the solutions I've found online. Blacklisting other characters in the string doesn't work as this removes some of the characters in the part I need. I've tried printing the specific character position using:

```
print(up_GDPgrowthRate[158]
print(up_GDPgrowthRate[159]
print(up_GDPgrowthRate[160]
etc
```

But this prints the characters on separate lines. Splitting also has the same problem, as I can't print it out on one line and assign the words to a variable. How to I get "GDP Growth Rate" as a single string without characters I don't need?

Comment: Try `up_GDPgrowthRate = bs.findAll("td")[21].text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
s = '''td stylepaddingleft px textalign left fontweight  whitespace normal
a hrefunitedkingdomgdpgrowth

                                                            GDP Growth Rate

                                                            span classtableunit smallspan
atd'''

print(s[s.index('GDP Growth Rate'):s.index('GDP Growth Rate')+len('GDP Growth Rate')])
```

`str.index()` accepts an argument of string and with slicing `[]` we can tell which part of a string we need. You need the start of the `GDP Growth Rate` + the length of `GDP Growth Rate`.